# Reading sample data from mp3 stream with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mp3, vlc

Hi guys thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

What I've done so far is:

```
const CHANNEL_LENGTH:int = 256;

var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 

var s:Sound = new Sound();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://someremote.url:8080/mp3_audio"); 

var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(0, false); 

s.load(req, context); 
s.play();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, readSpectrum);

function readSpectrum(event:Event){
    SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(bytes, true, 0);
    // bytes.bytesAvailable is always 2048

    for(var i = 0; i < CHANNEL_LENGTH; i += 8){
        var n:Number = bytes.readFloat();
        trace(n); // always 0's
    }
}
```

The problem is that n returns nothing. Which I don't understand because I can hear the audio fine through the speakers so I know it's being decoded.

I'm using VLC to transcode the audio to MP3 server side.

Any Ideas?